# Not able to share my spreadsheet after making changes to an excel file with anyone?

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I have Macbook M2 Air.

I have made changes to an excel file in my mac spreadsheet now I am sharing it to someone but change is not reflecting?

I saved my file and mailed as well as send that file through the document via whatsApp, but the file didn't get changes done by me.

I am trying it through my macbook.

Comment: That would suggest that either you didn't actually save the changes, or you sent the old version of the file. I suggest you amend your question to include where the file is stored (locally / cloud / email) and how **precisely** you shared it.

Comment: If your file is on a cloud location, maybe you are not logged in for it to be synced